# Possible to use 'git diff' or a local Git client to view diffs for very large files in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, diff, atom-editor

I'm a technical editor who uses GitBash, GitHub, and Atom for file management and editing. I've run into a problem with editing files that are so large that the diffs won't appear in GitHub. However, we really need the diffs to appear there so that the writers we work with can review them. I emailed GitHub support and they said "[1]. You'll need to view the diffs locally, using `git diff` on the command line [2] or a local Git client." Can anyone explain to me how these solutions might work? Would either of them make it possible for someone to review the diffs in GitHub or is this just not possible with files over a certain size? Before this I'd never heard of 'git diff' or a local Git client. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Git is a software that runs on a computer (either yours or github.com's servers). However git the software does not have a built in UI. There are many ways to control and visualize this software such as

- Github.com, Bitbucket.com
- Command line (Terminal)
- A git client (SourceTree, Github Desktop)

The command line and git client run on your machines. They may have less limitations than github.com in terms of CPU and RAM usage.

However, command line and the client will only show you the diffs. I have not heard of being able to review and comment on code with the client and command line like you could in github.com

An alternative to github.com is bitbucket. Perhaps they have higher limits? If the review matters a lot to you [Fisheye and Crucible](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crucible/crucible-and-fisheye-298977540.html) might be the solution but I'm not aware of their size limitations.